# Tem algum recurso do Eclipse que inclua "this." antes de toda variável onde isto for implícito?

Tags: java, eclipse

Toda hora eu me vejo colocando `this.` antes das variáveis que são atributos de classe em métodos não estáticos.

O eclipse tem alguma opção que aplique isso em todos os arquivos de código fonte?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Você pode definir isso em *Window->Preferences->Java->Code Style->Clean Up*.

Crie um novo profile, ou edite o atual.

Vá na aba *Member Accesses*.

Marque: *Use 'this' qualifies for field accesses* ; depois só marcar *Always*.

Feito tudo isso, só ir ao menu *Source->Clean Up*.

Comment: Complementando: você facilmente pode criar um atalho para esse comando, tal qual `Ctrl+Shift+O`

Answer (score 1):

Também pode ser definido para corrigir automaticamente ao salvar a classe através do Save Actions (*Window->Preferences->Java->Editor->Save Actions*).

Ative o checkbox *Additional actions* e selecione *Configure...* .

Na aba *Member Accesses*, selecione *Use 'this' qualifier for field accesses* e ative *Always*.

OBS: Também pode ser configurado para métodos.

Clique em OK, feche a tela de preferences e já estará ativo ao salvar os arquivos.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 0):

Se o que você quer é evitar a digitação do `this.` antes de cada variável, basta usar `ctrl + espaço` que as variáveis pertencentes ao escopo de `this.` aparecerão para você escolher (recurso autocompletar).

Comment: eu queria algo do tipo ctrl+shift+o